# Can I get an Array of the indices of neighbors in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of 0s and 1s and I am looking for a method to get an array that returns an array with all indices of 1s and two neighboring 1s.

It might be easier to understand with an example:

```
array =[[[0 0 0 0]
    [0 1 1 0]
    [0 1 1 0]
    [0 0 0 0]]

    [[0 0 0 0]
    [0 1 1 0]
    [0 1 1 0]
    [0 0 0 0]]]
```

what I'm looking for is a function that returns:

```
result= [
[[0 1 1] [0 1 2] [0 2 1]]
[[0 1 1] [0 2 2] [0 2 1]]
[[0 1 1] [0 1 2] [0 2 2]]
[[0 1 1] [1 1 1] [0 2 2]]
[[0 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 2]]
...]
```

I am currently working with for loops, iterating through the array and checking manually if there are neighbors, but that's very, very slow and I hope, that there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

if you use numpy you could do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
array =np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0]],

    [[0, 0, 0 ,0],
    [0, 1 ,1 ,0],
    [0 ,1, 1 ,0],
    [0 ,0 ,0, 0]]])
```

indexing positions with 1:

```
idx1 = array == 1
```

using [np.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) we can calculate difference and index 0 in the diff array

```
idx2 = np.diff(array,append=0)
```

use logical_and to get indexes of 1s with neighbouring 1s

```
np.where(np.logical_and(idx1,idx2))

Out[55]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction, but this returns only the indices of 1s, which would still leave me with the manual check for the direct neighbors of each of these points, which is the main problem for me.

Comment: @Julius_Strack so you only want the index where the neighbour is 1?

Comment: the array I have with the 1s and 0s is a representation of some 3D model. I want to create an exportable stl file, from that, and the best possibility I could find for this is the numpy-stl package. But this package needs triangles to compute. So I am looking for something that would return these triangles for me, aka the indices of the 1 and two direct neighboring 1s in an array. So instead of the [[011] [012] [021] [022] ...] that dstack gives me, I want a [[[011][012][022]] [[011][012][021]] ...] where I have the 1 and all dircet neighbors as three points in an array-like structure.